# working examples of js.amcharts in python

Tags: python, amcharts

I came across this [link](https://pypi.org/project/js.amcharts) for using js.amcharts in python, but couldn't find any working examples of the same. I did try googling but no luck. Can someone please help me on this? I like the 3d charts in amcharts and thus want to generate a PDF in python and embed the charts in it. Please help.

Comment: have you checked this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75405001/make-pdf-using-python-and-amcharts5

Comment: Thanks for that. Went through the link, and it looks like he is looking to convert html to pdf. Whereas I want to generate amcharts into a pdf along with few other info.

Answer (score 0):

you may create a method in python that provide data to the html page where the amchart will plot and you may render it

def get_pie_3D(self, args, token,charttype):

```
    data = self.get_data(args, token)
    
                
    return render_template('amchart3Dpie.html', data=data)
```

here amchart3Dpie.html is used to generate your AmChartpie

```
<title>AmChart Example</title>

<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>




<style>

    .chart_div div {

        padding-top: 30px;

    }

</style>
```

```
<div >

    <div id="chartdiv" class="chart_div"></div>

</div>






<script>

    // Add your JavaScript code to create the AmChart

    // For example, you can use the following code to create a simple pie chart

    var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart3D);

    chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0;

    //console.log("{{data}}")

    data= JSON.parse("{{data}}".replaceAll('&#39;','\"'))

    // Set up the chart

    chart.data = data;

    //chart.innerRadius = am4core.percent(40);

    chart.depth = 20;

    /// Create series  of type PieSeries3D will be responsible for rendering the slices of the pie chart

    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries3D());

    series.dataFields.value = "Value"; 

    series.dataFields.category = "EntityName";

    // Configure appearance

    series.ticks.template.disabled = true;

    series.labels.template.text = "{EntityName}: {Value}%";

    series.slices.template.tooltipText = "{EntityName}: {Value}%";

    series.slices.template.cornerRadius = 10;

    series.colors.step = 3;

    chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

    // Enable export

    chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();

    // Clean up the chart when the page is unloaded

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {

        chart.dispose();

    });

</script>
```